# How to get image height from dom tree using jQuery when height attribute is not set

Tags: jquery

I want to get image height and width when it is not set from height attribute and not also set in css. Real height and width of image which we get in dom tree or when browser render image with image's original height and width.
I tried following but didn't worked,

```
$("#idname img").attr('height');
```

but this need height attribute to set in image<>

Comment: There is a method called `height`.

Comment: height is not an attribute, it is a style property. try to access it via .css( propertyName ) http://api.jquery.com/css/ or you can use the heigt function on the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the height method

```
$("#idname img").height()
```

but you have to call it in the window-load event (instead of the dom-ready) because images are not loaded in the dom.

```
$(window).load(function ()
```

Comment: can I call it on page load event

Comment: Yes, this is what `$(window).load(function ()` does

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#idname img").height()
```

Comment: Note that it is important _when_ you call this method. It's not `ready`-friendly.